# Command-based application: How should I handle command names?

Tags: java, inheritance, command-line, interface, command-line-interface

I want to program a command-based application. My current structure is the following:

```
public abstract class Command {
    public abstract void execute();
}

public class AddCommand extends Command {
    public static final String COMMAND_NAME = "add";

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Executing add command");
    }
}

public class QuitCommand extends Command {
    public static final String COMMAND_NAME = "quit";

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Executing quit command");
    }
}
```

The thing I dislike is that every command has a name, but the Command class doesn't require that. So if you forget to implement the execute method, an error will be thrown. However, if I forget to implement the COMMAND_NAME, nothing happens. Therefore I would like to add this to the Command class, but I don't know how.

I am planning to use the name to link the commands with their string representation in a Map to easily run the corresponding command entered by the user.

If you have any other tips or a better approach (e.g. use of interfaces), feel free to add them as well.

Comment: Don't make the `COMMAND_NAME`s static. They should be instance fields if you want to look them up in a map.

Comment: @Sweeper Having those static fields is not a problem per se, but not having a `name()` or similar method in the interface/abstract class **is**.